# No IIS Manager on Windows Server 2012 Essentials

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, iis, essentials-2012

I just got Windows Server 2012 Essentials installed on a VM and I would like to set up some web projects in IIS on this VM. But I can't seem to find how to get to it? When I remote to the machine with my admin account all I seem to have access to is the dashboard.

I understand that it comes already installed but where is it?

I have tried the suggestions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510466/where-is-iis-on-windows-server-2012-essentials) and got nothing! The actual manager is no where to be found!

Answer (score 1):

I removed it and reinstalled it again and made sure the management console was selected this time.